# Read a value in the component controller

Tags: angularjs, components

Let's say I have a component as following :

```
.component('book', {
    bindings: {
        type: '=?'
    },...
});
```

So in the parent controller I've to declare `type` as `vm.type = null;`, and call this component as : `<book type="vm.type" />`

Here if I set the value of `vm.type` to `true` in the component controller I'll get the value as `true`.

So what I want is only to access the value of `vm.type` inside the parent controller which can be only set inside the component controller, in other words: `vm.type` is a readonly variable inside the parent controller, but it can be changed in the component controller.

One way binding won't work obviously since the value of `vm.type` in the parent controller won't change if I changed it in the component controller.

How can I solve that ?

Comment: You want to read parent's variable inside child controller, right?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide nope, I want to read a component controller variable inside the parent controller, this variable can be only changed inside the component's controller, and cannot be changed in the parent controller

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between parent and child controllers using `$emit` and `$broadcast`, if you want to read child variable in parent controller, you can do the following:

**child.controller**

```
$scope.yourVariable = 'Data to send';
$scope.$emit('yourCustomEventName', $scope.yourVariable); // will emit event with data to parent controller
```

**parent.controller**

```
// $scope.$on will catch your custom event
$scope.$on('yourCustomEventName', function (event, data) {
  console.log(data); // will print "Data to send", received from child controller
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the model to be "readonly" from parent component then you have not to change it via parent component. The component architecture is tree-like, so parent is higher than child.

To sum up, in your case you need just to update model on child component and then pass the updated value on parent component via some binding event.

Notice the following code, also [here's a working fiddle demonstrating the following code](https://jsfiddle.net/39ysaod9/):

Child component:

```
.component('child', {
  bindings: {
    onValueChange: '&'
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.total = 0;
    this.increaseTotal = () => {
      this.total++;
      this.onValueChange({
        value: this.total
      }); // Here you updated the parent model
    };
  },
  template: `<button ng-click="$ctrl.increaseTotal()">Increase total</button>`
})
```

Parent component:

```
.component('parent', {
  controller: function() {
    this.setValue = (val) => {
      this.childValue = val;
    };
  },
  template: `Total in Parent Component: {{$ctrl.childValue}} 
                    <child on-value-change="$ctrl.setValue(value)"></child>`
})
```